# null-safe mapping Comparator using default implementations

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

Is there a build-in possibility to create a null-safe mapping comparator in Java 8 without writing a own implementation of `Comparator`?

When running the following code, it causes a NPE because the `keyExtractor` argument of `Comparator.comparing()` may return a `null` value:

```
public class ToSort
{

    private String sortBy;

    public ToSort(String sortBy)
    {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }

    public String getSortBy()
    {
        return sortBy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // mapping comparator
        Comparator<ToSort> comp = Comparator.comparing(ToSort::getSortBy);                          
        SortedSet<ToSort> set = new TreeSet<>(comp);
        ToSort o1 = new ToSort("1");
        ToSort o2 = new ToSort(null);

        set.add(o1);

        System.out.println(set.contains(o2)); //NPE because o2.getSortBy() == null

    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
>       at java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$2/1480010240.compare(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
>       at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:376)
>       at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:345)
>       at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:232)
>       at java.util.TreeSet.contains(TreeSet.java:234)
>       at test.ToSort.main(ToSort.java:48)

Using

```
Comparator<ToSort> comp = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(ToSort::getSortBy));
```

does not work either as only `ToSort` objects that are `null` are treaded properly.

I know how to write my own `Comparator` implementation, I`m just searching a more "elegant" solution like

```
Comparator.comparingNullsFirst(ToSort::getSortBy)
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Found a possible solution:

```
Comparator.comparing(ToSort::getSortBy, 
      Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
)
```

Comment: So the reason this solution works is because of the order of nesting of comparators. In your question the innermost comparator (and therefore the first to be executed) was `ToSort::getSortBy` and the `nullsFirst` was wrapped around it. In this answer the `nullsFirst` comparator is now executed first, providing safety before the null-returning `getSortBy` calls

Answer (score 3):

Snippet for streams:

```
somePersonList
    .stream()
    .sorted(
        Comparator.comparing(SomePerson::getName,
        Comparator.nullsLast(String::compareTo))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```