# How to sort on the basis of both age and name of two different persons using Comparator?

Tags: java

i have to sort candiadates on the basics of both name and age .here the data

Arun 20
Bucky 22
Arun 25

and the output has to be

Arun 25
    Arun 20
    Bucky 22

here the coding

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;

    public int compareTo(Student s1) {
          return this.age-s1.age;
       }

    //Constructor
    public Student(String name,int id,int age) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name="";
        this.id=0;
        this.age=0;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Here the main class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;

public class StudentList {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student s1= new Student(null, 0, 0);
        s1.setName("Andy");
        s1.setAge(25);
        s1.setId(1);
        Student s2=new Student(null, 0, 0);
        s2.setName("Brad");
        s2.setAge(22);
        s2.setId(2);
        Student s3=new Student(null, 0, 0);
        s3.setName("Andy");
        s3.setAge(30);
        s3.setId(3);
        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        Collections.sort(list);

        for(Student a:list){
            System.out.println(a.getName()+""+a.getAge());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should change your `compareTo()` method:

```
public int compareTo(Student s1) {
     int nameCompare = this.name.compareTo(s1.name == null ? "" : s1.name);
     if(nameCompare == 0) return Integer.compare(this.age, s1.age);
     return nameCompare;
}
```

Comment: Error:The method compare(String, String) is undefined for the type String        help me to resolve this

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: The compareTo() shall not throw NullPointerException when name is null. The Student API clearly allows for name being null and the compareTo shall handle that.

Comment: @Michal Right, fixed it

Comment: Now the compareTo() is not symmetric, i.e. it behaves differently  based on whether s1.compareTo(s2) or s2.compareTo(s1) is called, provided one of s1 and s2 has name equal to null.

Comment: And how would you safely do such asymmetric call?

Comment: In production code I would never implement comparison on my own, I would actually use Anton's answer and either make the Student object immutable and always fully initialized or enhance the comparator with Comparator.nullFirst / Comparator.nullsLast as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499846/null-safe-mapping-comparator-using-default-implementations.

Comment: Just for the fun - for nulls last perhaps something like this.name==null ? s1.name!=null ? -1 : 0 : s1.name == null ? 1 : this.name.compareTo(s1.name) but please note I do not have a compiler at hand so this might or might not work. I would need to write quite a a few unit tests to prove the concept.

Comment: I probably would use methods from Java 8 as well but I wanted to point OP to the errors in his code. Answering my own question, I thinks there is no way to do two separate assymmetric calls as compareTo is unary method.

Comment: Error:The method compare(String, String) is undefined for the type help me to resolve this @michal @ ΔλЛ

Comment: I was writing from memory, corrected it later - you should use `String.compareTo(String)`.

Answer (score 2):

using the stream power of java8 you define 2 comparators (one by name and one by age)

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
Comparator<Student> byName = (x, y) -> x.name.compareTo(y.name);
Comparator<Student> byAge = (l, r) -> Integer.compare(r.age, l.age);

list.add(new Student("Andy", 25, 1));
list.add(new Student("Brad", 22, 2));
list.add(new Student("Andy", 30, 3));


list.stream().sorted(byName.thenComparing(byAge)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

then **stream -> sorted -> thenComparing** (this is doing the trick is the first criteria returns that they are the same :))

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use `Java-8`? You can just use `Comparator.comparing` method. For example:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge).thenComparing(Student::getName));
```

It will sort list of students based on age and then based on name; Or you can use `Stream#sorted` if you don't want to change the order of elements in the original list:

```
List<Student> sorted = list.stream().
    sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge).thenComparing(Student::getName).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Arun 20 Bucky 22 Arun 25

and the output has to be

> Arun 25 Arun 20 Bucky 22

You want to sort by name ASC then by age DESC

Implement Comparable in this way :

```
public int compareTo(Student other) {

   int nameComparison = String.compare(this.name, other.name)
   if (nameComparison != 0){           
       return nameComparison;
   }
      // DESC  order
   return -Integer.compare(age, other.age);
 }
```